# Squeeze text to fit in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, css-transforms

I have a "wall" of quare-sized Bootstrap button with one fontawesome icon and two lines of text (`<span>`) below. Sometimes, the text for each line can be too long, so it wraps naturally. I want to prevent that. However, it is a requirement, that the full text must be displayed. I also don't want to break the tile layout by enlarging single tiles.

Therefore, my idea was to use a CSS `transform: scaleX(?)` to squeeze the text in case. But I don't have a reference to the actual width of the text. Also, the with of the tiles is based on relative units, so I can't use any fixed pixel values.

Here's my current css declatation:

```html
<style>
    .flex-container .btn-lg {
        width: 20vmin;
        height: 20vmin;
        margin: 8px;
        font-size: 3.5vmin;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: normal;
    }

    .btn-tile > * {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>

<div data-bind="foreach: $data.entries" class="flex-container">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-tile storageType-3" data-bind="click: e, class: 'storageType-' + d.type">
        <i class="fas fa-ramp-loading" data-bind="class: d.icon"></i>
        <span data-bind="text: d.desc1"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: d.desc2" style=" /* Experimental */
            transform: scaleX(.8);
            white-space: nowrap;
        ">This text is way too long</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

If the texts `desc1` or `desc2` are too long, a scaleX should be applied, so that they fit inside the fixed size button.

Is this even possible with pure CSS, or do I need to iterate over the tiles with Javascript, read the actual widths and calculate the scaling factor like that?

I'm using knockout binding, by the way.

**Edit:**

I did some experimenting, but I still can't calculate the correct scaling factor. The correct factor should be somewhere around .3 for a longer text. It returns 0.477, though.

```
1 / $('.btn-tile').first().children().last()[0].scrollWidth * ($('.btn-tile')[0].offsetWidth)
```

Comment: You could put a conditional class on on the span `text.length > 10 && '.shrink'` and adjust the size of your text in CSS this way. Drawback obviously being that it is not dynamic but it will give you two styling options fast and simple

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane Thank you for your suggestion. But I need a sulution which works with texts of various lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use the difference in `scrollWidth` and `clientWidth` in overflowing elements to compute the ideal scaling that would fit the entire parent element, and apply that as a `scaleX` transform to the overflowing element.

Don't forget to set the transform origin to the left side of the object, since it is overflowing on the right.

Unfortunately I don't think you can do this in pure CSS as you need to compute the scrollWidth and clientWidth. But here is a minimal example of how you can do this:

```js
els = document.querySelectorAll(".possibly-scaled");
for (let el of els) {
    let xScale = el.clientWidth / el.scrollWidth;
    if (xScale < 1) { 
        el.style.transform = "scaleX(" + xScale + ")";
    }
}
```

```css
.fixed-width {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 8px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;

    /* necessary styling */
    width: 80px;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.possibly-scaled {
    /* necessary styling */
    display: block;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width">
    <span class="possibly-scaled">OK</span>
</div>
<div class="fixed-width">
    <span class="possibly-scaled">Good</span>
</div>
<div class="fixed-width">
    <span class="possibly-scaled">Fantastic!</span>
</div>
<div class="fixed-width">
    <span class="possibly-scaled">Amazingly, this also fits.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much! The only thing that I have to solve now is how to make this work with knockout.js, because the fixed-width elements are generated dynamically.

Comment: Do you have some kind of callback function that gets called when you generate a new element? If so, use the code in the for loop in that callback (with `el` = the new element).

Comment: Not really. I use knockout.js, where everything is data-bound. I'm already looking for an event. Fortunately, all the buttons are generated from the same template, so maybe there is an init handler or something.

Comment: I don't know knockout.js myself and I don't plan to read through all of the documentation myself, but it seems like this is a good place to start: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-lifecycle-events.html

Comment: I found the solution. Knockout emits the `afterRender` event in template binding. I just wrote a global viewmodel method, that does the exact same calculation as in your example. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove

Comment: By the way, I wonder, if there is a better solution for my filtering. Right now, I use jQuery for that: `for (let el of $(elements).find('span'))`. `elements` is an array that consists of all child elements of my template. Is there a simple vanilla.js replacement for that without iterating over the whole array again?

Comment: @AndréReichelt You could use jQuery's `.each(callback);` instead, but internally that's just another for loop. It is more consistent with jQuery-style code though. See jQuery docs for details.

Answer (score 1):

for ie

```
var x, i;
        x = document.querySelectorAll(".possibly-scaled");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            //x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            let xScale = x[i].clientWidth / x[i].scrollWidth;
            console.log('aaa' + xScale);
            if (xScale < 1)
                x[i].style.transform = "scaleX(" + xScale + ")";
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!